# How to find currently running applications in android when > LOLLIPOP?

Tags: java, android

My app has to get the information about the applications currently running on foreground.

I tried get all running proccess:

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) MyApplication.getAppContext().getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> processInfoList = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
```

This work only when version < LOLLIPOP. I tried many solutions from Stackoverflow, but none work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Its Lollipop...not lillipop

Answer (score -1):

See `UsageStatsManager`

You can get latest apps used like that :

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DATE), 0, 0);

UsageStatsManager usageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
List<UsageStats> usageStatsList = usageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), System.currentTimeMillis());
```

and Having `List<UsageStats>` you can get an app with maximum `lastTimeUsed` to get current app in foreground. Remember to add permissions!